# How to update Wine to the latest version?

Tags: 11.10, wine

I just formatted my laptop and got rid of Windows 7. Yay ;-)

Either way, Wine is version 1.3.28 here, and I need it to update (there are some bugfixes) for my game so I need a more recent version. This is the version I got from the Ubuntu software manager. How do I get a more recent version or Wine version 1.4?

I've already added the repo into my repository, but still no updates.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Moderator Note**: The ubuntu-wine PPA is no longer maintained and as such this is **NOT** the solution to follow as of 2022.  For historical reasons, however, this answer will remain.

Add the correct repo

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

Update your sources list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Update or install `wine` to the version on the PPA

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.3
```

Note: even tough the package name is `wine1.3` the listed version on the Ubuntu wine packagers PPA contains version *1.4~rc1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~oneiric1*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2017-March/117104.html), for Wine, Launchpad is no longer used for the Ubuntu builds.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, since you have the 1.3.x repository it means you have the PPA from the wine site (**ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa**). You will have to wait until Scott Ritchie gets time to update to it. Right now he updated to the RC1 for the 1.4 branch. RC2 came today but like always the update depends on whether he gets time today or the following days.

Remember that even if the developing branch is called 1.3.x it really is the "Alpha" or Work in Progress versions of the 1.4.

In WINE, the **ODD** versions are for development. The **EVEN** versions are the stable ones.

So the 1.0.x was the stable and 1.1.x was the development versions for 1.2

Then the 1.2.x was the stable and the 1.3.x was the development versions for 1.4

When 1.4 comes out you will see 1.4 as the stable version and 1.5.x as the development branch.

For more information see [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)