# How do I copy program files from Windows partition to my Ubuntu partition

Tags: partitioning, wine, clipboard

I am dual-booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 and I play World of Warcraft on my Windows OS.  I've been thinking about running WoW in Ubuntu but I have no idea how to copy the game files from the window partition to the Ubuntu OS partition.

I've downloaded Wine for support of WoW in Ubuntu but I'm kinda stuck here.  So how do I copy WoW in the wine directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose you want, you actually do not need to copy the files over. you can run WOW from within the windows partition. What you really have to do is the following to have everything working as it should:

1. Install the PPA for WINE. You HAVE TO install the PPA which is much better. More info here: [How to update Wine to the latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100947/how-to-update-wine-to-the-latest-version)
2. Install using winetricks (After having installed Wine) all DirectX 9 components. Since the release of Wine 1.4, you can just install the DirectX that comes with any Windows CD/DVD (eg: The DirectX 10 that comes with Skyrim). That should be enough to get DirectX working.
3. Install the latest drivers for Intel, Nvidia or Ati. All of which you can find/install with this PPA: [How do I install the latest Nvidia drivers via the Additional Drivers tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104527/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-via-the-additional-drivers-tool)
4. Follow this link with any additional relevant information about WoW: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25610
5. Create a desktop shortcut/launcher as mentioned in this question to have a working one click icon: [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand/128284#128284) (Easy way here: https://askubuntu.com/a/128284/7035 )
6. Edit the Desktop shortcut and in the command line type: `wine "DIR" -opengl` where DIR is the complete location of your Wow.exe file. For example in my case `wine "/media/fun/games/World of Warcraft/Wow.exe" -opengl"`. The OpenGL is to give you more available graphics options. You can also remove it but for most video cards it is better to have it there to make the game run smoother.

If you still want to copy the Wow folder, you can put it on your Ubuntu home folder and do the same steps mentioned before. Just wanted to point out that you can run the game from the same Windows partition, does saving you space and time.

Comment: @ Luis Alvarado Hello, Should i install all the d3dx9_**.dll files?  Can this cause problems for me at all? I read that wine doesn't recommend using directx although these file types can be useful.  What are they for exactly? thank you for your help also:)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Wine's FAQ:

Short answer: you have to install them in Wine just like you did in Windows. Applications usually have a setup or installer program.

http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-35dc1c1d64fb6da2753ff03a1dea1d261f240d11

The above link has detailed instructions on how to install Windows' applications in Wine.