# How to install a higher version of wine?

Tags: installation, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update Wine to the latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100947/how-to-update-wine-to-the-latest-version)

The default version of Wine in Ubuntu 12.04 is 1.4. I would like to install the latest version of wine. I wonder how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install latest Wine in Ubuntu via PPA. Open Terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and copy the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

Source : [NoobsLabs](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/06/install-wine-156-in-ubuntu-1204.html)

Note: The above answer is outdated now and only goes up to Wine 1.8. For the latest Wine version, you can add this repository instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt update
sudo apt winehq-devel
```

From the answer to [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892230/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-wine-as-the-system-version/892235#892235)

Comment: Is 1.5 a stable version of wine?

Comment: the stable version from WineHQ is Wine 1.4.1

Comment: version 1.5 is still in beta

Comment: yup its still in dev.