# How to install the latest version of WINE as the system version?

Tags: wine, repository

I *usually* use PlayOnLinux to manage my WINE versions via the interface, however, I would like to change my "system" WINE version (the version that loads when I double-click a file) so that I can just double-click on files to run them in the latest version of WINE even if they're the same "wineprefix". I have read the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192116/how-to-install-a-higher-version-of-wine) but the versions in that repository only go up to version 1.8.

I would like the ability to make my system version of WINE 2.3 and keep it updated to the latest version automatically, so I don't want to manually compile or download packages all the time.

Also, if possible, I would like my system version to be a 32-bit one, and to instead use PlayOnLinux if I need a 64-bit wineprefix.

I am running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit.

EDIT: I thought I'd include a list of commands to wipe & update Wine (EDIT 2: updated for 18.04, EDIT 3: Updated again for Ubuntu 18.04 in 2019):

```
# Remove old Wine
rm -Rf ~/.wine
sudo apt purge -y wine*

# Add key and repo
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo add-apt-repository -y 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main' 
sudo add-apt-repository -y 'ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport' 
rm -f winehq.key

# Install
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
sudo apt install -y winehq-devel playonlinux

# This is optional, but some programs need it.
sudo sed -i -e 's/scope = 1/scope = 0/g' /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf 

# Did it work?
wine --version
```

Thanks to everyone who answered. This doesn't include changing Winearch, see below for that.

Comment: Also you may want to try Playonlinux, it allow the install of the latest wine versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install latest WINE version for Ubuntu

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install winehq-devel
```

Run 32-bit WINE for default (rm old `~/.wine` folder first)

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine winecfg
```

You can change different `WINEPREFIX` folder for 32-bit and 64-bit WINE environment

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/win32 winecfg
```

Or

```
WINEARCH=win64 WINEPREFIX=~/win64 winecfg
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for, very informative!

Comment: What sucks is that 16 days after you answered my question, the answer changed... https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2017-March/117104.html

Comment: `!!! PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS REPOSITORY IS DEPRECATED !!!`

Answer (score 7):

So you know that Wine has moved to the new repository.

Now let me share the commands here:

```
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'
```

See: [Packaging related changes](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2017-March/117104.html).

Comment: Or follow the official instructions: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu