# Has wine been updated for newest ubuntu?

Tags: wine

Trying to get some windows programs running on ubuntu.  Some will run others no.  Wondering if wine has been up dated for latest ubuntu version?
Charley

Comment: Wine from the repo should always be the latest stable version. Could you say what version of ubuntu you're referring to?

Comment: Not all Windows applications run in Wine. Take a look on their homepage if your applications are verified to run. Also take a look at Play On Linux: https://www.playonlinux.com/

Comment: "What version of <program> will be in the next release of Ubuntu?" questions are off topic. You can always watch the packages on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net) if you wish to know, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the latest version of WINE as the system version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892230/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-wine-as-the-system-version)

Answer (score 1):

https://packages.ubuntu.com/

This shows the version of all packages for all supported releases of ubuntu. https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/artful/wine shows the latest stable version of wine. The development version is not finished until it is released nor is it supported here.

So artful has a newer version 2.0.2 with wine stable compared to 1.6.8 in xenial. So it has been updated since the last LTS that has been released and with this you can always check if a new version of ubuntu for now on. This is the general solution to this problem and you can search for all packages.

Although not all windows programs run in wine but your question currently has no details on those programs so I unfortanetly can't help you.

Comment: artful is a STS (short term support) release. Bionic is what's currently in development. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases