# Installing WIne

Tags: 18.04, wine

I'm struggling with installing Wine on fresh   Description: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

```
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.*.* 80]
:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic               
Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is    
therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user      
configuration details.

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

I've been trying from official site https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu and also youtube videos, but both ends with the same error (above)

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the latest version of WINE as the system version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892230/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-wine-as-the-system-version)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xenial repository does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/xenial-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 0):

**Install Wine 3.0.3 in Ubuntu:**
1. Open terminal via Ctrl+Alt+T or by searching it from app launcher. When it opens, run command to add the repository key:
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key && sudo apt-key add winehq.key
2. Add wine repository via command:
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
3. Finally check updates and install wine stable packages:
sudo apt-get update
                                                          sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
**Uninstall:**
sudo apt-get remove --autoremove wine-stable wine-stable-amd64