# A few questions before I get Ubuntu

Tags: wine

I don't really know if this is the right place to ask these questions, but I would like to clear these up. Ok, so, Ubuntu sounds awesome, but I heard it has Wine on it already? If it does, that's awesome. If not, well, I like Wine. Also, this is basically a version of Linux, correct? I just wanted to know if this stuff is correct or not. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ubuntu is a Linux distribution, yes. WINE can be installed as a package and if you want even more you might want to have a look at the (commercial) CrossOver products, which will also help WINE development in the process ;)

Comment: @Jonas If you haven't already spend a few minutes exploring http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/features

Comment: I recommend PlayOnLinux over Crossover, it's easier to use and it seems more Windows programs are supported.

Comment: I could see a possible argument for closing this as NARQ since it is not a (single) question. But *not constructive*. Can someone who has voted to close please comment to explain why? This is asking for concrete information. I made an answer to give this information. (I have also somewhat synthesized the two separate questions. Sort of.)

Answer (score 1):

[Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) is the [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29) that Ubuntu and many other [operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) use. Operating systems that use Linux as their kernel and use it with the most common libraries and tools (for example, [GNU libc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library)) are called [Linux distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) or GNU/Linux distributions.

Confusingly, while Linux is a kernel, [the term Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnu/linux) is also sometimes used to refer to Linux-based operating systems (i.e., "Linux distributions"), or to refer to their shared characteristics that some people consider to comprise an operating system (of which all Linux distributions, also called GNU/Linux distributions, can be considered parallel variations). The term GNU/Linux also refers to this (and is not the name of a kernel).

All the above terms are widely considered correct, though all of them are also considered wrong by a few people here and there. You can read about [the naming controversies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_naming_controversy) if you like. During the ordinary course or using and talking about operating systems and kernels, they usually don't get in the way too much and most of the time terms are widely understood however they are used, from context.

As you may be aware, Wine is an emulation layer that provides an infrastructure running Windows programs. Many Windows programs run well on Wine, but also plenty run poorly or not at all. Wine runs *on* a wider variety of platforms than "Linux" systems. It runs on GNU/Linux distributions like Ubuntu, but also on other [Unix-like systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like), such as FreeBSD and Mac OS X.

**Ubuntu does not come with Wine installed by default, but you can install it easily.** Wine is officially packaged for Ubuntu and Wine in Ubuntu is maintained officially by the Ubuntu community (it is provided through Ubuntu's official software sources). Just open the Software Center, type in Wine, and install it when given the option to do so.

Wine is provided by the [wine [image: Install wine]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine) package. You can also install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine
```

If you want to install the latest version of wine, see [these instructions](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) and/or [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100947/how-to-update-wine-to-the-latest-version). The Wine PPA should be pretty safe but it's a good idea [to read these guidelines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out) before using it or any other PPAs.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't really know if this is the right place to ask these questions

Yes, this is the right place to ask such question(s), despite someone down-voting the question.

> I heard it has Wine on it already?

No, Ubuntu does not have Wine pre-installed. You can install it from the Ubuntu Software Center or in a terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine
```

Note: I would recommend looking for alternate native applications similar to (and mostly even better than) Windows applications instead of installing an emulation platform like Wine. For example, you could use Gimp in place of Photoshop. Libre Office is an open source office suite with which you can completely forget MS Office (you can open/edit/convert MS Office documents on the fly). There are several games too. I am an information technology services, systems and resources integrator using Ubuntu since 2010 and haven't felt the need for Wine yet.

> this is basically a version of Linux, correct?

No, Ubuntu is not a Linux version, but a Linux distribution from Canonical Ltd. You can know more about Ubuntu [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/).